# Link directly to an App View in Django Baton Menu

Tags: django, django-baton

Using [Baton](https://github.com/otto-torino/django-baton), I want to link directly to a particular view in an app.

Can fudge it by just hard-coding the URL:

```
    BATON = {
    "SITE_HEADER": "My App",
    "MENU": (
       
        {
            "type": "app",
            "name": "core",
            "label": "Management",
            "icon": "fa fa-cog",
            "models": (
                {"name": "client", "label": "Clients"},
                {"name": "invoice", "label": "Invoices"},
            ),
        },
        {
            "type": "free",
            "name": "docs",
            "label": "Documentation",
            "icon": "fa fa-info",
            "url": "https://www.myurl.com/docs/",
        },
    ),
```

Tried using "view" or "views" the way Models is done:

```
{
    "type": "app",
    "name": "docs",
    "label": "Documentation",
    "icon": "fa fa-info",
    "view": {"docs_general"},
},
```

And

```
{
    "type": "app",
    "name": "docs",
    "label": "Documentation",
    "icon": "fa fa-info",
    "views": ({"docs_general"}),
},
```

Doesn't seem to be documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is mapped within `urls.py`, so just use a soft link:

```
   BATON = {
    "SITE_HEADER": "My App",
    "MENU": (
       
        {
            "type": "app",
            "name": "core",
            "label": "Management",
            "icon": "fa fa-cog",
            "models": (
                {"name": "client", "label": "Clients"},
                {"name": "invoice", "label": "Invoices"},
            ),
        },
        {
            "type": "free",
            "name": "docs",
            "label": "Documentation",
            "icon": "fa fa-info",
            "url": "/docs/",
        },
    ),
```